# custom listview fling exception

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm start to learning android and have a problem. On my Gesture listener in "OnFling" method i've got a NullPointerException with e1 argument, but e2 arg are pointing normally. Please, help.

My Activity code are following below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public dbWorker d = null;
    public ArrayList<Row> newsContainer = new ArrayList<Row>();
    private static ArrayList<Row> cached = new ArrayList<Row>();
    public static int cache_guid = 0;
    public static Row selectedItem = null;


    private ListView newsList = null;
    ListArrayAdapter aa = null;

    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        d = new dbWorker(this);
        cache_guid = d.getMaxGuid();
        newsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        aa = new ListArrayAdapter(this, newsContainer);
        newsList.setAdapter(aa);
        newsList.setClickable(true);
        newsList.setBackgroundColor(color.holo_blue_dark);

        refreshRssList();
        setTitle("Rss Reader/ Main page");
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,new MyGestureDetector(), null, false);

        // Set the touch listener for the main view to be our custom gesture listener
        newsList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        newsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

            }

        });
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), FavActivity.class);

            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }

            /* right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            startActivity(intent);
            MainActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(
            R.anim.slide_in_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left
            );

            // right to left swipe
            }  else */
            if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            startActivity(intent);
            MainActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(
            R.anim.slide_in_left, 
            R.anim.slide_out_right
            );
            }

            return false;
        }

        // It is necessary to return true from onDown for the onFling event to register
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    private void refreshRssList() {

        ArrayList<Row> newItems = rssWorker.getNews(this);
        ArrayList<Row> for_save = new ArrayList<Row>();

        if (dbWorker.readAll() != null)
            cached = dbWorker.readAll();

        if (newItems == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection error!", 3).show();
            return;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < newItems.size(); i++)
        {
            Row tmp = newItems.get(i);
            cached.add(tmp);
            for_save.add(tmp);
        }

        newsContainer.clear();

        if (cached != null)
            newsContainer.addAll(cached);

        d.SaveAll(for_save);

        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
}
```

And ArrayAdapter:

package com.example.rssreader;

```
public final class ListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row> {

    private final Context c;
    private final List<Row> items;

    public ListArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Row> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.list, objects);
        c = context;
        items = objects;
    }


      @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          final Row selectedItem = items.get(position);

          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
          TextView newsTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
          final ImageView favIcon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          LinearLayout newsLay = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listLayout);

          Date d = new Date();
          d.setTime(selectedItem.pubdate);
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd - hh:mm:ss");

          newsTitle.setText(selectedItem.name + " " + sdf.format(d));

          if (selectedItem.isRead == 0)
              newsLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
          else
              newsLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

          if (selectedItem.isFav ==  1)
          {
                favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_name_selected);
            } else {
                favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_name_unselected);
            }
          favIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectedItem.isFav == 1){
                    favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_name_unselected);
                    selectedItem.isFav = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_name_selected);
                    selectedItem.isFav = 1;
                }
                dbWorker.SaveState(selectedItem);
            }

          });
          newsTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    MainActivity.selectedItem = selectedItem;
                    c.startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ItemActivity.class));

                    if (selectedItem.isRead != 1)
                    {
                        selectedItem.isRead = 1;
                        dbWorker.SaveState(selectedItem);
                    }
                }
          });
          return rowView;
        }

}
```

Comment: Please add the NullPointerException error from the log.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.example.rssreader.MainActivity$MyGestureDetector.onFling(MainActivity.java:79)
E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:600)
08-14 19:23:02.260: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.example.rssreader.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:57)
 E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7241)
E/AndroidRuntime(790): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me before when trying to include onFling listeners in ListViews. It seems that if your ListView is still detecting some touch events (e.g., touch, or normal scroll) it will consume the motionEvents. Therefore you have to be prepared for the MotionEvents to sometimes be null.

Comment: This motion events - are arguments of onFling method. How i can determine it before?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The fundamental problem is that (IIRC) as long as you're using a ListView, you won't be able to trust the custom onFling method's parameters. I don't think there's any way around that. I could be wrong, of course.